# Android How can I hide notification alert when the app is closed?

Tags: android, onesignal

I implement the onesignal app on android. It works fine. But I want to send notification from web to all users with custom data and I want to users dont see any notification on bar. Of course I do something in the background when notificatin comes.

How can I do that?

thanks in advance

### my code:

```
OneSignal.startInit(this)
        .setNotificationReceivedHandler(new NotificationReceivedHandler())
        .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new NotificationOpenedHandler())
        .init();

OneSignal.setSubscription(true);
```

**I do something here**

```
class NotificationReceivedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationReceivedHandler {
        @Override
        public void notificationReceived(OSNotification notification) {
            JSONObject data = notification.payload.additionalData;
            String customKey;

            if (data != null) {
                customKey = data.optString("custom", null);
                if (customKey != null)
                {
                    //I do sth here
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you once check with below code snippet ?

```
 class NotificationReceivedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationReceivedHandler {
        @Override
        public void notificationReceived(OSNotification notification) {
            JSONObject data = notification.payload.additionalData;
            String customKey;

            if (data != null) {
                customKey = data.optString("custom", null);
                if (customKey != null)
                {
                    //I do sth here
                    NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    nMgr.cancelAll();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If still facing issue post issue here : https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/issues

Answer (score 1):

call this metod on your Activity's onBackPressed() metod

```
public void cancelNotification() {

    String ns = NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) YourActivity.this.getSystemService(ns);
    nMgr.cancel(1);
}
```

Comment: Do you perhaps know how to dismiss/cancel the notification on the application launcher icon? There is a "1" displaying on the icon and if I don't open the notification the "1" remains there